# change the template of e-mail message sent when admin changes password/e-mail adress

Tags: wordpress

Lots of our users forgot e-mail adress details and passwords for our website and they are asking me to help them log in.
When I change their password/e-mail adress they receive an e-mail message like this:

> Blockquote

```
From: WordPress <wordpress@example.com>
To: username@example.com
Subject: [WordPress] Password Changed

Hi username,

This notice confirms that your password was changed on WordPress.

If you did not change your password, please contact the Site Administrator at admin@example.com

This email has been sent to username@example.com

Regards,
All at WordPress
http://example.com/
```

I'd like to customize the message which is sent, but this template doesn't appear in the /wp-admin/Emails tab, like the message which is sent when users change their password themselves.
Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 3):

See this - add to your functions file

```
 <?php  // <<  remove this 
 // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/

 add_filter('password_change_email', 'wpse207879_change_password_mail_message', 10, 3 );
 function wpse207879_change_password_mail_message( $pass_change_mail, $user, $userdata) {


 /* placeholders are:
 '###USERNAME###'
 '###ADMIN_EMAIL###'
 '###EMAIL###'
 '###SITENAME###'
 '###SITEURL###'

 */         
        
  $new_message_txt = __( '
  Hi ###USERNAME###,

  This notice confirms that your password on ###SITENAME### was recently changed.

  If you did not change your password, please contact us ASAP via our website contact page: ###SITEURL###.

  This email has been sent to ###EMAIL###.

  Regards,
  All at ###SITENAME###
  ###SITEURL###' 

);


  $pass_change_mail[ 'message' ] = $new_message_txt;
    return $pass_change_mail;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it, following Wordpress guidelines is by using add_filer for the password_change_email hook.
Do not change wp-includes files as recommended above, as it will be overrun by future WP releases.

you can add the filter in your functions.php file of your theme, or in a plugin.

here's how it should look like roughly:

```
function my_theme_password_change_email($pass_change_email, $user, $userdata){
   //do your changes here
}
add_filter( "password_change_email", "my_theme_password_change_email",10,3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The file where these emails are handled are in the root of your wordpress installation. The exact file is wp-login.php. I hope this helps.

Comment: There might be the code to send those emails, but not the template.

Answer (score -3):

Just edit below file from root directory located in **/wp-includes/user.php** line no. 2009 or search for **'Hi ###USERNAME###,** and you will find the message body as below that you can customize it as you would like.

```html
$pass_change_text = __(
'Hi ###USERNAME###,

This notice confirms that your password was changed on ###SITENAME###.

If you did not change your password, please contact the Site Administrator at ###ADMIN_EMAIL###

This email has been sent to ###EMAIL###

Regards,
All at ###SITENAME###
###SITEURL###'
            );
```

Comment: wp-includes files should never be edited, this is against wp guidelines, and will probably be overriden by any future wp release