# How to change the content of password changed email.Is this possible?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am a beginner in wordpress.I'm doing an ecommerce website and the problem is when the user reset their password after changing it a mail has been sent to the user (like your password has been changed).How can i change the email text content when the password is successfully changed and then an email is being sent to the user?

After changing the password the user is getting the following mail-

Hello abc

To inform you that your password has been changed.

If it was not you, please contact the following site administrator. 
exampleadmin@gmail.com

This e-mail has been sent to customermailid@gmail.com

Comment: You need to share what you've done so far. Share some code examples first, that you've tried.

Comment: I did signup as a customer and then i reset the password, after changing the password i got the mail which i have edited in my question.Is this possible to change the email content of password has been changed? i have searched it in all files but couldn't get any content like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to modify emails content in your theme functions file (functions.php):

/* Start Of Function for changing the Forgot password mail content */

```
add_filter('retrieve_password_message', 'forgot_mail_contnet', 10, 2);

function forgot_mail_contnet($message, $key) {

    $user_data = '';
    // If no value is posted, return false
    if (!isset($_POST['user_login'])) {
        return '';
    }
    // Fetch user information from user_login
    if (strpos($_POST['user_login'], '@')) {

        $user_data = get_user_by('email', trim($_POST['user_login']));
    } else {
        $login = trim($_POST['user_login']);
        $user_data = get_user_by('login', $login);
    }
    if (!$user_data) {
        return '';
    }
    $user_login = $user_data->user_login;
    $user_email = $user_data->user_email;

    $site_url = get_site_url();

    $reset_url = network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login');

    // here $message it the mail content , which you can modify as per your requirment and $key is activation key
    // after modifying you must return $message
    return $message . "- <a href=' " . $reset_url . " '> click Here </a>";
}

/* End Of Function for changing the Forgot password mail content */
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890751/change-the-template-of-e-mail-message-sent-when-admin-changes-password-e-mail-ad/57567993#57567993          please visit this url it's having the same issue, i hope now i would be able to make you understand properly

Comment: you can use after_password_reset hook or follow this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_password_change_notification/

Answer (score -2):

Just edit below file from root directory located in
**/wp-includes/user.php** line no. 2009 or search for **'Hi ###USERNAME###,** and you will find the message body as below that you can customize it as you would like.

```html
$pass_change_text = __(
'Hi ###USERNAME###,

This notice confirms that your password was changed on ###SITENAME###.

If you did not change your password, please contact the Site Administrator at ###ADMIN_EMAIL###

This email has been sent to ###EMAIL###

Regards,
All at ###SITENAME###
###SITEURL###'
            );
```